# Словосочетание "в солнце" в значении "в солнечную погоду": корректно ли?

Tags: значение-слов, фразеология, семантика, словосочетания

Скажите, насколько корректно говорить "в солнце" в значении "в солнечную погоду"? Говорим же мы "в дождь", "в слякоть", " в ветер" и пр.

Например: "В дождь они сидели за картами, а в солнце катались на велосипедах". Звучит вроде нормально, а "Они шли в солнце" — уже не очень, хотя "Они шли в дождь" — не так коробит. Возможно, вкусовщина. Но в целом, можно ведь говорить "в солнце"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Нацкорпусе есть примеры с подобным использованием сочетания "в солнце":

> В непогодь они притихали, а в солнце выбирали самые что ни на есть
> сухие, сожжённые откосы. (Домбровский)

> Люди были легкие, зыбкие в солнце, не мешали. (Шапко)

Тем не менее это сочетание используется значительно реже, чем "в дождь/снег/метель/ураган/ночь" и проч.
Объяснение простое: во всех вышеперечисленных случаях описывается нечто, что человека окружает: дождь, ночь... А солнце человека не окружает, поэтому "в солнце" как синоним "в солнечную погоду" и звучит коробяще.

Comment: Да, вы правы, это должна быть характеристика пространства, внутри которого находится человек. А солнце, луна, звезды воспринимаются как отдельные объекты этого же пространства, хотя и связанные с погодой в нем.